# NDOF Invert Blender 2.8

Tags: customization, 3d-mouse

Is it possible to invert the NDOF pan and orbit and zoom directions in 2.8?

2.7 had an option to customise this. I use the default 3Dconexion settings but blender automatically flips them.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blender now responds to changes made in the 3DConnexion properties application (this wasn't previously the case in 2.79). 
If you reverse all the navigation properties in the 3DConnexion advanced settings, the space mouse will respond as if it was set up with default settings in Blender. In every other CAD program I have used the opposite is true.

I can't seem to find any documentation of these changes or why it is mapped wrong by default.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah the defaults for 3DConnexion motion direction are backwards, and the only way to fix it is by using the 3DC per-app settings.

This issue, https://developer.blender.org/T67579 , was inexplicably closed without this simple correction being made, despite Logan's excellent comment.